Odoo set response type for whole method or controller?
If there a way to set the response type for a whole method and/or controller in Odoo ?
I created custom controllers to return data formatted as json. The problem is when the data isn't found I receive a classic 404 page instead of a json formatted result.
Of course I could set the content_type of the response but I don't like it. The code clarity get worse because I have to repeat the content_type settings multiple times in my controllers.
This should be managed with a decorator, no?
class MySuperController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/devolive/review/<int:product_id>', method=['GET'])
    def get_review_data(self, product_id):
        #...
        if check:
            raise http.NotFound()  # Going to show a normal 404 page.
        #...
        return http.Response(json.dumps(result, default=json_default), content_type='application/json')


Try passing type='json' argument to http.route

no this change the request and response to json

if you want to use this method from an external app: How about using the builtin API to retrieve your data:
https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-connect-to-an-odoo-16-using-restful-api

You have to use type="json" in the controller. It will go like the following:
class MySuperController(http.Controller):

@http.route('/devolive/review/<int:product_id>', type="json", method=['GET'])
def get_review_data(self, product_id):
    return result

This will always return the data in JSON format.

No this will keep sending 404 or any other error with an HTML format in the response and will mandatory the format of the request to be json.
